# Cron expression that finishes half way through an hour

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, cronexpression

I am trying to create a cron expression that will repeat every 5 minutes from 12:00am to 2:30pm Monday through Friday. I am able to get an hour range to work properly when both sides of the range are at the top of an hour, for example 12:00am to 2:00pm (`0 0/5 0-14 ? * MON-FRI`). However, I can not seem to find a way to have a repeater every five minutes that finishes not at the top of an hour, like at 2:30pm. I am looking for something like this: `0 4/5 0-14:30 ? * MON-FRI` . Does anyone have any ideas? Anyone done this via a cron expression before? Thanks!

Comment: How timely - I was close to asking something similar!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with just plain cron expression. You can beef it up with a calendar that restricts the firing window. With calendar you can have easier expression of *every 5 minutes from Monday to Friday*. Then associate the trigger with DailyCalendar that limits execution to 00:00 - 14:30 range.

[See the tutorial for an example](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this idea out today.